# Взять потоком только уникальное значение List<T> C#

Tags: c#

В листе содержатся необходимые данные. Необходимо создавать поток и взять только то значение , которое еще не использовалось , т.е. следующее.

Все это заключено в цикле foreach

List list new List(); //создаем новый лист

Создаем 5-20 потоков

Каждый поток берет элемент из листа и работает с ним(элемент должен быть уникальным и не должен повторяться в других потоках когда либо)

### После того как в foreach кончились элементы необходимо завершить работу. Как это сделать?

Пробовал удалять поток после взятия - не дается, пишет что лист изменен и дальнейшая работа невозможна

Была идея: запускаем поток -> поток берет элемент и идет работать с ним -> элемент перекидываем вниз списка list -> через 500мс запускем следующий поток и т.д.
В таком случае взятые элементы будут всегда уникальными , но в конце концов они проделают ту же самую работу что и 1 поток

Comment: сделайте цикл не foreach, а for(int i =0; i<list.Count; i++)  . после всегда берите элемент с индексом 0 и удаляйте после взятия этот элемент

Comment: либо while(list.Count!=0) - берите элемент с индексом 0 и удаляйте этот элемент

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир лучше сделать через так наверное while (list.Count>0) {/какая-то логика, которая использует list.Last()/; 
list.Remove(list.Last()) }

Comment: @Ivan, да, надо в другом цикле работать, поскольку внутри foreach не получится изменить количество элементов списка

Comment: вообще-то не понятна задача - зачем именно удалять, в цикле foreach можно и не удалять элемент, каждый следующий в цикле будет не предыдущий, закончился обход, значит и закончится взятие каждого элемента, покажите Ваш код, чтобы было понятнее, в вопросе есть условие - уникальный, возможно Вам требуется выбрать сначала только элементы с уникальными значениями

Comment: @Архипов Владимир Предполагаю, что если если создаю поток 1 , беру из foreach элемент и переношу его в конец листа а так же использую и т.д. далее создаю следующий поток и для него будет лист новый и он так же будет проходить весь лист. Объяснять я не умею поэтому покажу
Изначальный массив 1 2 3 4 5 , мы взяли первый элемент перенесли его в конец списка и используем , получилось 2 3 4 5 1 , но ведь для следующего потока изначальным листом будет именно такая комбинация foreach и он будет проходить пока не заменчит именно ее и так далее. Я верносчитаю?

Comment: 5 потоков, первый берет элементы 0, 5, 10, второй берет 1, 6, 11, третий берет 2, 7, 12, четвертый 3, 8, 13, пятый 4, 9, 14. Так не подойдет?

Comment: @SelfishCrawler , в массиве >5000 элементов

Comment: каждый поток берёт только 1 элемент списка или каждый поток должен брать все элементы в порядке, когда предыдущий поток брал такой же порядок, только первый элемент должен быть последним или вообще просто уникальный порядок элементов должен брать?

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир , вот пример
Массив 1 2 3 4 5
Запускаем 3 потока
Поток 1 взял 1
Поток 2 взял 2 
Поток 3 взял 3
--------------
Цикл потоков кончился
--------------
Поток 1 взял 4
Поток 2 взял 5

Элементы кончились - потоки отключились

Comment: @Kain это был пример, имелось ввиду что поток 1 берет 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 итд элементы, второй берет 1 6 11 16 21 итд, надеюсь принцип понятен

Comment: в первом комментарии тогда решение, только надо делать проверку перед циклом на list.Count!=0 и запускать цикл не до конца, а на требуемое количество запускаемых сейчас потоков, т.е. сначала ```if(list.Count!=0) { тут цикл }``` и и сам цикл взятия значений в потоки ```for(int i=0; i<countRunThread&&list.Count!=0;i++) { //берём list[0]; list.RemoveAt(0);}``` и заканчиваем поднимать потоки, если list.Count == 0;

Comment: List не является потокобезопасной коллекцией. Если вам надо обработать элементы списка параллельно, используйте TPL, например `Parallel.ForEach(myList, item => dosmthg(item));`, если вам надо получать результат, используйте PLinq, например `var result = myList.AsParallel().Select(item=>doSmthg(item)).ToList();`

Comment: Используйте `ConcurrentQueue`. Это автоматически обеспечит и потокобезопасность, и доступ к новому элементу.

Comment: Возможно, достаточно применить `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach`. Или линковский `AsParallel`. Опишите подробней, какие именно типы содержатся в списке и какие действия с ними выполняются в потоках.

Comment: Если обработка каждого элемента непродолжительная, то постоянное создание новых потоков (тасков) очень неэффективно. Тогда нужно применить [Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies)

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир Как вы и посоветовали сделал через цикл for единственное что когда цикл заканчивается я поставил уведомление ввиде MessegeBox'a , однако оно вылезает равно количеству потоков(что в принципе логично). Посоветуйте , пожалуйста, есть супер-секретный код , как выполнить действие только 1 раз , или все таки привязать к объекту? Например изменение видимости кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void StartThread() //Создаем цикл потоков
        {
            var options = new ParallelOptions(); //создаем опции паралели
            options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = guna2TrackBar1.Value; //максимум паралельных потоков = значению на trackBar'e 
            Parallel.ForEach(myList, options, item => Run(item)); //стартуем потоки паралельно со списком , опциями и передает в сл метод нащу строку
        }
```

Помогло